# .then of $cordovaInAppBrowser is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

In an Ionic app, I am using `ngCordova's $cordovaInAppBrowser` to open Apple Play Store URL. It opens the app store but it does not go into .then. Relevant code:

```
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(mktUrl, '_system', {location: 'yes', clearcache: 'yes', toolbar: 'no'}).
then(function(event) { ¬                            
      console.log("inside then"); ¬                           
      $state.go('odetails');
    }¬
```

`mktUrl` is a app store URL for an app.

It does not generate any error. But it just doesn't work. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Been there.

If you change from `_system` to `_blank`, cordova uses same webview as your app container and the promises do work.

I am using this code:

```
            var inAppBrowserOptions = {
                location: 'yes',
                clearcache: 'no',
                hardwareback: 'no'
            };
            if (!site.toLowerCase().match(/^htt(p|ps):\/\//)) {
                site = 'http://' + site;
            }
            $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(
                site,
                '_blank', 
                inAppBrowserOptions
            ).then(function (event) { // success    
                    //$state.go('')
                    Toast.show('inAppBrowser success', 'short', 'bottom');

                }).catch(function (event) { // error
                    Toast.show('Error opening site', 'short', 'bottom');
                });
            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function (e, event) { 
                Toast.show('inAppBrowser exit', 'short', 'bottom');
            });
```